# Can't install libSDL2-2.0-0:i386

Tags: apt, package-management, sdl

I'm trying to run Star Conflict. It had troubles with libcurl, but I fixed that. Now, it wants the 32-bit version of libSDL2-2.0-0. No problem right? Well, this is what it says:

```
dirk@SUBNETDEFENSE:~$ sudo apt-get install libSDL2-2.0-0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Why these two completely unrelated packages jump in and demand that their broken dependencies are fixed in the first place is a mystery to me. I really don't care about those two, I have the 64-bit versions without any problems at all. I didn't even know I had the 32-bit versions.

How can I get around this?

Edit:
Output of `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Update: I managed to get this particular program running by putting a copy of libSDL2-2.0.so.0 that was already installed in Team Fortress 2's game directory. I still don't have a system-wide installation of the library, but you might want to try looking for the library in other game folders, and installing it in yours.

Comment: Please try `sudo apt-get -f install` (without package names) and post its output ([edit] your answer and then notify me with a comment when you're done).

Comment: @ByteCommander Done.

Comment: @ByteCommander Did you receive the message? I updated the question.